# Can't subscribe and check the content on micro-ROS

Tags: ros2, microcontroller, micro-ros

I'm trying to set up micro-ROS on Ubuntu 22.04 following the steps on this [website](https://medium.com/@SameerT009/connect-esp32-to-ros2-foxy-5f06e0cc64df), and connect ESP32 to ROS2.

However, though the connection is established (Step8 on this [website](https://medium.com/@SameerT009/connect-esp32-to-ros2-foxy-5f06e0cc64df)), it can't subscribe and check the content.

(When executing the command `ros2 topic list`, I can't see an additional topic `/freertos_int32_publisher`.)

Is there any solution?

[image]

[image]

Comment: Welcome to Robotics Stack Exchange! It is better to paste the text from the error rather than a screenshot. Images are not text-searchable. Thank you for your kind cooperation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it myself.
The reason why it couldn't subscribe and check the content was that `ROS_DOMAIN_ID` was set.
After I set `ROS_DOMAIN_ID` back to 0, it become able to subscribe and check the content. If you're faced with the same problem, please refer to this.